I am getting NamedUser instead of AuthenticatedUser even though I logged in via access token with PyGithub
I am new to PyGithub. I am trying to get all my repositories -- public, private, even the ones I am a collaborator in. However, I only seem to get my publicly owned repositories when I use the get_repos function.  I soon realized it's because the user that is being returned is a NamedUser rather than an Authenticated one. I get this error when I try to use other arguments in the get_repos function:

NamedUser.get_repos() got an unexpected keyword argument visibility

My code:
auth = Auth.Token(access_token)
g = Github(auth=auth)
user = g.get_user(username)
retrieved_repos = user.get_repos(type='all')

I read the documentation and other than putting the username and password directly, this seems to be the only way to login? I'm not sure why it's not giving me the authenticated access when I used a valid access token.
